# Error configuring relationship using Fluent

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am getting the following error when trying to configure my entities and relationships for an existing table:

> Models.Foo_Bar: : Multiplicity conflicts with
>   the referential constraint in Role 'Foo_Bar_Target'
>   in relationship 'Foo_Bar'. Because all of the
>   properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the
>   Principal Role must be '1'.

The system I am trying to model is if a user has a `Foo` it confers zero or more `Bar`, and conversely a user may have a `Bar` without a corresponding `Foo`

The Tables are configured as follows:

(not sure if it is relevant, but there are actually a few different types of `Foo` that can be mapped to a `Bar` and `Foo` is represented using Table per hierarchy in the DB)

User:

```
Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)
```

UserFoo:

```
Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1)
UserId INT NOT NULL

//Below is to do with TPH implementation, hopefully not 
//relevant here but included for sake of completeness
FooType1Id INT NULL 
FooType2Id INT NULL
```

UserBar:

```
UserId INT NOT NULL 
UserFooId INT NULL
BarId INT NOT NULL
```

And the entity classes to map this are as follows :

```
public abstract class UserFoo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class UserBar
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int? UserFooId { get; set; }
    public int BarId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual UserFoo UserFoo { get; set; }
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}
```

And the mapping is done as so:

```
public class UserFooMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserFoo>
{
    public UserFooMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.UserId).IsRequired();

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("UserFoo", "User");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.UserId).HasColumnName("UserId");

        // Relationships
        this.HasMany(t => t.UserBar)
            .WithOptional(t => t.UserFoo)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.UserFooId);
    }
}

public class UserBarMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserBar>
{
    public UserBarMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.BarId, t.UserFooId });

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("UserBar", "User");
        this.Property(t => t.UserId).HasColumnName("UserId");
        this.Property(t => t.UserFooId).HasColumnName("UserFooId");
        this.Property(t => t.BarId).HasColumnName("BarId");

        // Relationships
        this.HasOptional(t => t.UserFoo)
            .WithMany(t => t.UserBar)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.UserFooId);
    }
}
```

Judging from the error I think the issue arises from `UserFooId` being nullable on `UserBar` but I can't  see an error here. I am relatively new to both code first (which I know this technically isn't because we are trying to map onto an existing DB) and Table Per Hierarchy as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was on the `UserBar` Table, The column `UserFooId` had not been made nullable in the DB. Once this column was correctly set as nullable everything worked correctly.